# Automatic text adding in Eclipse editor from xtext dsl project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext, eclipse-pde, xtend

Here is a small code section I made from the DSL grammar generated using Xtext.

```
start
{
    alpha 
    {
         prev : alpha
         next : beta
    }
}
```

In this, I want that as soon as I write next :beta, automatically the code should change to this

```
start
{
    alpha 
    {
         prev : null
         next : beta
    }
    beta
    {
         prev : alpha
    }
}
```

What code do I need to add?

I think we can achieve this via some listener to the editor which listen for the changes in the editor and thus add code. But there isn't much support available so that I can clearly understand.

Comment: btw Xtext is a correct spelling

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve it by customizing content assist: https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/310_eclipse_support.html#content-assist

Comment: Ya, that I have integrated, but in content assist, it only suggests, but do not add automatically.

Comment: I see I thought if there is only one proposal then the content assist would apply it automatically. Try to make sure that you have a single one.

Comment: Ok, I will try and inforn